# Mulit-touch touchpad gestures Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, gestures, touchegg

I'm running 15.04 with the gnome shell. I was wondering if I could get macbook like touch pad gestures on Linux, did some research and found xSwipe and Touchegg.

I tried installing xSwipe and completely messed it up and ended up reinstalling Ubuntu.

I want to know if there is any other software like these out there, and which is the best one?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the xorg-input driver has three and four finger detection disabled.  In order to re-enable them you will have to patch the xserver-xorg-input-synaptics driver.

http://mangel312.blogspot.com/2015/02/enable-multitouch-on-dell-xps-13-9333.html